# Why does the Pandas rolling function produce initial NaNs with an Integer window but not with an Offset window?

Tags: pandas, datetime, indexing, time-series, rolling-computation

Using an Integer window argument for the Pandas rolling function produces NaN values for the initial number of values until it hits the size of the window, while using an equivalent Offset does not.
As an example,

```
>     df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('1/1/2020','1/31/2020',freq='D'),data={'A':np.arange(1,32,1)})
>     
>     df['intWindow'] = df['A'].rolling(3).sum()
>     
>     df['offsetWindow'] = df['A'].rolling('3D').sum()
>     
>     df.head()
>     
            A   intWindow   offsetWindow
2020-01-01  1   NaN         1.0
2020-01-02  2   NaN         3.0
2020-01-03  3   6.0         6.0
2020-01-04  4   9.0         9.0
2020-01-05  5   12.0        12.0
```

Unless I'm missing something, it seems like the offset option is producing inaccurate results for the initial values.   Is there an argument to return NaNs without setting them manually, afterward?

Comment: Rolling by time is a bit different from rolling by the number of rows. Use `min_periods=1`

Comment: Thanks.  Using min_periods=3 worked.  I still don't understand the motivation for not having initial NaNs be the default.